# Tkinter - How do I open a window?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

Say I have 2 files displaying different forms, a log in and a main menu. How do I open my main menu form after clicking log in (assuming the information is correct)?

Comment: This is a very broad question, so it is hard to answer it completely.  Ultimately though, One approach would be to have 2 frames -- one frame holding the log-in stuff and another frame holding the main menu.  When the user logs in successfully, you would `.grid_forget` the login frame and `.grid` the main menu frame in it's place.

Comment: Would they need to be in the same file or could I split them up into different files?

Comment: You mean the source?  You're free to split it up into as many modules as you think would make it most organized.

Answer (score 1):

When Tkinter starts up you automatically get one window. This window is called the *root* or *master* window, and it must exist as long as the app is running (though it can be hidden).

To create additional windows you need to create instances of the class [Toplevel](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm).

If you are trying to emulate a web GUI where everything stays in one window, you can choose a different strategy. For example, both your login form and your main form can be implemented inside individual instances of [Frame](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm). Then, after the user logs in, you can remove the login form from the root window and replace it with your other form.